# Inserting username and password at website using javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I was trying to make script which will auto-login me to website (http://gamers.ba/), but I can't get it to insert my username and password inside form. I tried this code:

```
javascript:document.forms['cssforms'].elements[username].value = MyUsername;
```

but nothing happens actually...

Also I tried this code:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('username').value = 'MyUsername';
```

but then I just get new blank page with "MyUsername" text at left upper corner...

This is part of code when I inspect that element in my Chrome:

```
    <form method="post" action="" class="cssform">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input style="width:355px;" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The form would need an `id` or a `name` to be referred to like that.

Comment: HOW are you calling it? A bookmarklet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me on http://gamers.ba/ as a bookmarklet

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('username').value='MyUsername';document.getElementById('password').value='MyPassword';document.forms.loginForma.submit.click();})();
```

Expanded:

```
javascript:(function(){
  document.getElementById('username').value='MyUsername';
  document.getElementById('password').value='MyPassword';
  document.forms.loginForma.submit.click();
})();
```

Obviously replace 'MyUsername' and 'MyPassword' with your username and password

Answer (score 0):

The form would need an `id` or a `name` to be referred to like that.  And `username` is a variable in your script, you need to use a string literal or [dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/1048572) instead.

To select the form by its class name, use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector):

```
document.querySelector("form.cssform").elements.username.value = Myusername;
```

If you want to select the hidden form (`<form class="formLoginTop" name="loginForma" action="/q/user/login" method="post">`), then you can still use

```
document.forms.loginForma.elements.username.value = Myusername;
```

But you could simply access the input element [by its id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById):

```
document.getElementById("username").value = Myusername;
```

(this will not work on http://gamers.ba/q/user/login, because there are *two* elements with the id `username` in that page)

Comment: Nothing happens when I enter that. Username field remains empty... I tried both ways...

Comment: Are you sure `Myusername` is not the empty string?

Comment: Tried adding it as 'Myusername', nothing changed... When I use second way you gave, if I surround Myusername with '', new blank page opens with "Myusername" text in upper left corner... You can try it yourself...

Comment: If you use it as a bookmarklet, the expression after `javascript` needs to return `undefined`. In your case, you could do `javascript: document.getElementById("username").value = "Myusername"; void 0;`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var MyUsername = 'markzuck';
document.getElementById('username').value = MyUsername;
```

Check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yrmk8j0v/1/).

Also, I would strongly recommend you start using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It makes the coding simpler and faster.

Comment: You mean on your website? Or on jsfiddle?

Comment: On website... It works perfectly on jsfiddle... Actually you did same as I did in second way I described, which should work, but apparently it's not working on this website...

Comment: Please check your Chrome console to check for specific errors and paste them here.

Comment: No errors in Chrome console but if I surround Myusername with apostrophes, like 'MyUsername', new blank page opens with "Myusername" text in upper left corner... You can try it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

This one fails:

document.forms['cssforms'].elements[username].value = MyUsername;

Because

- The form does not have the name "cssforms". A class does not make it a form
- And `[username]` is an undefined variable.

---

And your second one fails because you are not cancelling the default action. I am assuming you are using a bookmarklet. You can either use void() or wrap it in a function

```
javascript:(function(){ document.getElementById('username').value = 'MyUsername'; })();
```